# How to use sp_helptext with schema without quotes (for query shortcuts)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2016

All my procedures, views are in schema `xx`. I know I have to use quotes in this case and when I run

```
exec sp_helptext 'xx.my_procedure'
```

it works fine.

However I would love to use query shortcuts (I am using SSMS 16) for sp_helptext.

When I select text and run shortcut I am getting:

> Incorrect syntaxt near '.'

which is obviously due to missing quotes in selected text.

Is there a way to workaround this?

Probably something that could temporarily add quotes via simple shortcut? Or maybe some other procedure that would nest `sp_helptext` and fix the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are another approaches for achieving your target,

but **mine** is as following:-

Create a procedure that executing `SP_HELPTEXT` after override it.

assuming the scema name is `XX`

```
Create procedure usp_helptext (@myObject varchar(255))
as
begin
declare @Query nvarchar(1000)
set @Query = 'exec sp_helptext ''XX.' + @myObject + ''''
print @Query
exec (@Query)
end
```

and execute the created proecure as next:-

```
exec usp_helptext proc_name.
```

Finally use a shortcut for usp_helptext rather than `sp_helptext`.